# update-rc.d command

Tags: linux, debian

I have some script I want to autorun it.
I am using such command:

```
 update-rc.d tdpsd defaults
```

and it fails with the following error:

```
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 6) of script `tdpsd' overwrites defaults (0 1 6 S)
```

I understand the meaning of the error, but I can't find any solution how to solve it without passing custom runlevels?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error. It's just a notification that the init script that you're loading has unusual runlevels -- if you really don't want it to run in the S (single-user) runlevel, just ignore the message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And if I want to run it in single-user runlevel?